# docker and composer install

Tags: docker, composer-php, docker-compose

I am having problems with docker-compose getting php-fpm container up with composer install.

I have folder structure like:

```
docker-compose.yml
containers/
    nginx
        Dockerfile
    php-fpm
        Dockerfile
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
    nginx:
        build:
            context: ./containers/nginx
        ports:
            - 80:80
    php-fpm:
        build:
            context: ./containers/php-fpm
        tty: true
```

and in php-fpm/Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1.5-fpm-alpine

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /srv/www

ENTRYPOINT composer install --prefer-source --no-interaction --no-autoloader
```

With current ENTRYPOINT, it seems that composer install gets stuck at "Generating autoload files", because nothing after that is outputted and container does not appear in **docker ps** list.

How can I keep above folder structure, but still able to run composer install after build or run (in this case I would need to add if conditions)?

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that you need a composer.json.

Please, follow these steps:

1. Go to [Get composer web -> getting started](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) and create a composer.json file.
2. Put this `composer.json` file in your dir structure as follows, for example:

   - docker-compose.yml
   - containers/

     - nginx

       - Dockerfile
     - php-fpm

       - Dockerfile
   - **composer/**

     - **composer.json**
3. Mount volume (modifying your docker-compose.yml file) to share composer.json to `/var/www/html` in `php-fpm` docker, because although you specify `/srv/www/` as workdir, composer looks up in `/var/www/html`.

```
    version: '3'

    services:
        nginx:
            build:
                context: ./containers/nginx
            ports:
                - "80:80"
        php-fpm:
            build:
                context: ./containers/php-fpm
            tty: true
            volumes:
                - ./composer/composer.json:/var/www/html/composer.json
```

I hope it's useful for you.